# How to save data from a form in Craft? Explain with an example?

Tags: form, controller

where do you handle the POST requests?
where do you write the validation rules and flash error messages?
where do you write save to db code?
(mainly i want to know how do you route a POST request to a controller and where do you write the controller?)

Answer (score 1):

You'd do this wiht a Craft plugin or module.

Try giving the plugin docs a once over: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend and if you have some specific questions, feel free to post back.

You can also generate Craft plugin boilerplate code at https://pluginfactory.io that already has a lot of this setup for you.

Comment: i never thought my quetsion would get answered ,thanx a lot man...btw i already knew that much.